# Css visibility property div1 hovering another div(div2)

Tags: html, css, hover

I am hiding a div with the class .text with

```
 div.text{

 visibility:hidden;
      }
```

This div is surrounded by another div with the class .col3

```
<div class="col3">
 <div class="image-box">
 <div class="text"> test </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I want the visibility to change to "visible" when i hover col3

i tried

```
.col3:hover + div.text {

visibility:visible;
}
```

however it doesnt seem to work this way.
strange thing is , when i do

```
 .image-box:hover + div.text{
 visibility:visible;
  }
```

It does show the text div when i hover the image box, but thats not what i want, i want it to show when i hover the surrounding div......

any help is welcome...

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
.col3:hover div.text {
    visibility:visible;
 }
```

The use of the `+` selector is incorrect as it targets elements directly following the first element. More information can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1139776/1838483).

Answer (score 3):

`+` in CSS is known as an ["adjacent *sibling* combinator"](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators). A sibling is an element which is contained within the same parent as another element. In this case, your `.image-box` element is a sibling of your `.text` element. Both of these elements are *children* of your `.col3` element. Your first selector will not select anything as `.text` isn't a sibling of `.col3`.

You'll need to use either a [descendant combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#descendant-combinators):

```css
.col3:hover div.text {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Or a [child combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#child-combinators):

```css
.col3:hover > div.text {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason why your

```
.col3:hover + div.text
```

Isn't working is because you're using an adjacent selector. What you're basically saying is "Take any div-node with the class text, that is lying on the same level as .col3, and do something with it when .col3 is hovered". But there isn't any. The div.text is not on the same level as .col3, but a direct child of it.

What you want to do is:

```
.col3:hover > div.text {
    visibility:visible;
}
```

Which says "Take any div.text which is a direct child node of .col3, and do something with it, when .col3 is hovered".