# Appending a div on unknodw div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have three divs. How should I append a div onto an unknown div?

```
<div class="main" >
 <div id="drag-box" >
  <div id="" class=""> </div>
 </div>
  </div>
```

I want to append div on an unknown div which is come after drag-box div. I don't know which div comes after drag-box div. But there must be one div after drag-box div.

Comment: I don't want to use id , class of that unknown div

Comment: you should really consider reading about the DOM :-) at mdn i have linked it in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#drag-box div:first-child").append("<span />");
```

or

```
$("#drag-box div").first().prepend("<span>first</span>");
```

For a complete answers, here it is working:

http://jsfiddle.net/dMUD3/

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  $("#drag-box div:first-child").attr("id");
```

Comment: @MichalB. have you ever used jquery? Try to read this one before posting any thing http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/

Comment: no worries, I perfectly understand what it does. OP asked how to append to/after a div without the id and you try to fetch the id for him...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of giving you a one liner I would like to give you an indepth solution.

A browser takes your html and parses what is called a DOM Tree out of it.

so if your html is .

```
<div class="a">
   <div class="foo"></div>
   <button class="foogle"></button>
</div>
```

The tree structure will become something like

```
 `-div.a
  |-div.foo
   `Button.foogle
```

**You should actually look into DOM Api's at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM)**

How DOM helps ?

With DOM api's you can actually access the unknown div using the reference to a known div. So if you actually understand your markup and its representation in DOM it should be pretty simple to get reference to nth child of an element;

You can access the child elements by the children attribute.

So

```
 // Get reference to the element.
 var parent = document.getElementById("drag-box");

 // Use the dom.
 var child_i_want = parent.children[0];
 // or there is another way
 var child_i_reallyWant = parent.firstElementChild;
```

There are solutions with jQuery but I feel its important for you to Understand basics of DOM even when there are helpful abstraction libraries in existance.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the + selector. It applies to the object directly following. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139763/what-does-the-plus-sign-css-selector-mean).

```
.drag-box + div {

}
```

Comment: This is for a div after it. Like `<div class="drag-box"></div> <div></div>`. That is how I interpreted 'come after' but it appears you actually wanted the first child element.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('<div></div>').appendTo($('#drag-box div:first'))
```