# Selecting more that one class in css 3

Tags: class, css, selector

Today I was looking at some sample code I found and noticed that the developer used a "+" instead of a "," to select two classes.

```
.region + .region{
    border-left: 1px solid lightgray;
    padding-left: 3.5%;
    margin-left: 4%;
}
```

What does the "+" sign do that the "," doesn't? Why would you use it? curiously the same class was selected twice here. Why?

Here is a link to the code pen... http://codepen.io/adobe/pen/vKixh

Im just learning CSS3 and any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139763/what-does-the-plus-sign-css-selector-mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## +s and ~s Are Siblings

```
<div>
    <div class="c"></div>
    <div class="x"></div>
    <div class="y"></div>
</div>
```

using `.c + div {}` will style `"x"` **CSS ONLY WORKS DOWNWARDS!**

## ,s Are Multiple Classes

```
<div>
    <div class="c"></div>
    <div class="x"></div>
</div>
```

using `.c, .x {}` will style both `"c"` and `"x"` the same way.

## No Space Means More Conditions

```
<div>
    <div class="c x"></div>
    <div class="c"></div>
    <div class="x"></div>
</div>
```

using `.c.x {}` will style `"c x"`

Answer (score 6):

**They are NOT the same!**

`+` is the adjacency selector, e.g. selects `.region` elements following `.region` elements.

A comma separated list simply allows you to apply one block of styling to multiple classes, thus:

```
.region, .region{}
```

Wouldn't actually perform any action that just `.region{}` wouldnt by itself.

**Adjacency selector** ([MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors))

> (+) This is referred to as an adjacent selector. It will select only the
>   specified element that immediately follows the former specified
>   element.

This in mind, `.region + .region{}` would only apply the styling to a `.region` after  another one, and NOT one in isolation, or the first.

Comment: I think we need to stress they're **not the same**! hah

Comment: @IanClark - done, just for you!

Comment: .region + .region{} refers to all regions which have a region just before itself. In a list of regions, this will apply to all but the first one

Comment: @Johan - I realise this wasnt clear so have clarified the last part, thanks

Comment: Just what I needed to know. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This is **not** an alternative notation to `,` (comma): the `+` has a totally different meaning, because it is the immediate sibling selector (or adjacent selector), so your rule matches  a `.region` element only when it's adjacent to another previous `.region` element.

If you have several sibling `.region` elements, like this

```
<div class="region">...</div>
<div class="region">...</div>
<div class="region">...</div>
<div class="region">...</div>
```

`.region + .region` will match every `.region` element except the first one.

Since this a `CSS2` selector, an equivalent `CSS3` selector would be `.region:nth-child(n+1)`