# CKEditor v4: Indent after heading

Tags: html, css, ckeditor

Is it possible to indent after a heading tag (h1-h6)?
I tried it with CSS and the CKEditor dataprocessor.

I need the following work-flow:
User:

1. Write a heading and set it to h1
2. Enter some text after the h1 heading

Output:

```
<h1>Heading h1</h1>
<p style="margin-left: 40px;">Content</p>
```

Attempt in CSS:

```
p {
     text-indent: 40px;
     /* or -> margin-left: 40px; */
}
```

But then it is set for all p-tags

Is this possible with CKEditor or should I solve this with CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `contents.css`:

```
h1 + p {
    text-indent: 40px;
}
```

And see: [What does the "+" (plus sign) CSS selector mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139763/what-does-the-plus-sign-css-selector-mean)

Comment: Wow this was fast. I found the sibling definitions seconds before and want to share the exact same solution.