# How does work of these two div:hover div and div:hover + div?

Tags: css

I tried both of these, but both are working same.

```
div:hover div
{
.....
}

div:hover + div
{
.....
}
```

Still there is any difference between these?

Comment: this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139763/what-does-the-plus-sign-css-selector-mean

Comment: [**The 30 CSS Selectors you Must Memorize**](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048)

Answer (score 3):

`div:hover div` will style a `div` *inside* the hovered `div`:

```
<div>
  I'm hovered.

  <div>
    So I'm styled.
  </div>
</div>
```

`div:hover + div` will style the `div` *following* the hovered `div`:

```
<div>
  I'm hovered.
</div>
<div>
  So I'm styled.
</div>
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 3px;
}

div.styleinner:hover div {
  background-color: red;
}

div.stylenext:hover + div {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="styleinner">Hover me
  <div>and I get styled</div>
</div>
<div>but I won't</div>

<div class="stylenext">Hover me
  <div>and I won't get styled</div>
</div>
<div>but I will</div>
```

Comment: Perfect explanation! Thanks :)