# Positioning an image below another image when a mouse hovers over an image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make image two appear below image one when a mouse hovers over image one.

```
<ul>
   <li>
    <img id="img1" src="imageone.png">
    <br>
    <img id="img2" src="imagetwo.png">  
  </li>
</ul>
```

Help is appreciated!

So far I have this CSS which does not seem to work

```
#img2 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}
#img1:hover + #img2,
#img2:hover {

 display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The `+`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1139763/11683) selects siblings that are immediately after. Your images are not, because they are separated with a `<br>`.

[Use `~`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10782054/11683) instead:

```css
#img1:hover ~ #img2
```

Answer (score 1):

You are very close.

First, remove the `<br>` tag since it breaks the adjacent sibling selector.

The hover works as long as you over over the first image.

If you apply `display: block` to the `img`, then you don't need the `<br>` tag.

Depending on your layout, the tilde (`~`) selector could also work but it depends on whether you have other images in the layout (I am thinking a photo gallery).

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
#img2 {
  display: none;
}
#img1:hover + #img2 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li>
    <img id="img1" src="http://placehold.it/150x50">
    <img id="img2" src="http://placehold.it/150x50">  
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I think your answer is more complete actually. I wont know until I include more images later in my design. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

use the tilde instead of the + sign, because you have a br inbetween

```css
#img2 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}
#img1:hover ~ #img2,
#img2:hover {

 display:block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li>
    <img id="img1" src="imageone.png">
    <br>
    <img id="img2" src="imagetwo.png">  
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be after something like this:

```css
.parent{
  position: relative;
}
.holder{
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color: #efefef;
}
.img{
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color: #ffefef;
}
#img2{
  display: none;
}
.holder:hover #img2{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li class="parent">
     <div class="holder">
       <img class="img" id="img1" src="imageone.png">
       <br>
       <img class="img" id="img2" src="imagetwo.png">  
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```