# Jquery: select an element when two or more conditions are true

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element like this

```
 <ul>
  <li data-ud="321" data-id="42">
  <li data-ud="322" data-id="42">
  <li data-ud="323" data-id="42">
  <li data-ud="324" data-id="42">

  <li data-ud="321" data-id="43">
  <li data-ud="322" data-id="43">
  <li data-ud="323" data-id="43">
  <li data-ud="324" data-id="43">

  <li data-ud="321" data-id="44">
  <li data-ud="322" data-id="44">
  <li data-ud="323" data-id="44">
  <li data-ud="324" data-id="44">

  <li data-ud="321" data-id="45">
  <li data-ud="322" data-id="45">
  <li data-ud="323" data-id="45">
  <li data-ud="324" data-id="45">

 </ul>
```

Now I want to select a element with data-id=45 and data-ud=322. I have tried but it didn't work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you show what  you have tried that didnt work maybe we can help with that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use 'and' in a selector, simply don't use any other separator, eg a `li` and class `myclass` would be:

```
li.myclass
```

to find by attribute, use `[attribute=x]`, so to combine the two:

```
li[data-id=45][data-ud=322]
```

or, with jquery:

```
$("li[data-id=45][data-ud=322]")
```

This can be difficult to read and prone to errors eg a space between the two `[][]` will give a totally different result, so you can instead use `filter` to the same effect:

```
$("li").filter("[data-id=45]").filter("[data-ud=322]")
```

Fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/o9fdhphf/

Comment: thanks bro for you detailed explanation and examples

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
$('li[data-id=45][data-ud=322 ]');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("[data-ud=322][data-id=45]").text()
```

OR

```
$("[data-ud=321] + [data-id=45]").text()
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/jenson555/d5k1acag/4/)

Comment: Did you check your fiddle?

Comment: @freedomn-m Sorry, Updated..Thankx!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139763/what-does-the-plus-sign-css-selector-mean   `[ud=321] + [id=45]` gives the element with id=45 that comes *after* ud=321, not that has both ud=321 and id=45 (ie it might have a different ud)