# How to use multiple "Attribute Equals" selector in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes, element

If you want to select a jquery element with 1 attribute that equals a value is simple:

```
$(".element[attribute1='true']").hide();
```

But what if you want to select an element with 2 equal attributes?

```
$(".element[attribute1='true', attribute2='false']").hide();
```

That won't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery: select an element when two or more conditions are true](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37136123/jquery-select-an-element-when-two-or-more-conditions-are-true)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use multiple [Attribute Equals Selector `[name=”value”]`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) in jquery like bottom code:

```
$(".element[attribute1='true'][attribute2='false']").hide();
```