# Get Element with multiple attributes match

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check a checkbox whose name and value I know, but I cannot use it this way. How can I select with 2 values?

```
$('[name="' + key + '"  value="' + value[i] + '"]').attr('checked', true);
```

Comment: `$("[attr=val][attr2=val2]")`   no space and each attribute in its own `[]`

Comment: oops.. I thought I tried that, it did.

Comment: Didn't notice my own comment linking to my own answer with more explanation :)  [select an element with two or more conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37136123/jquery-select-an-element-when-two-or-more-conditions-are-true)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join your attribute selectors `[][]`

```js
$(`[name="${key}"][value="${value[i]}"]`).prop({checked: true});
```

The above uses the more readable [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) instead of string concatenation using `+`