# How to place a tag element between the input tag and the hidden field?

Tags: css, spring, checkbox, label

I am using the Spring form tag library in one of my projects and encountered the following problem:

I need to call a JavaScript function onmouseup on the label to a checkbox.

The problem is with the Spring form:checkbox tag the output then looks like this

```
<input id="id" name="name" value="true" type="checkbox">
<input name="_name" value="on" type="hidden"> 
<label for="id" onmouseup="func()" >blabla</label>
```

Due to my style.css which uses the + selector to get the label after a checked checkbox I need something like:

```
<input id="id" name="name" value="true" type="checkbox">
<label for="id" onmouseup="func()" >blabla</label>
<input name="_name" value="on" type="hidden">
```

But because I want to call a function onmouseup on the label, the label attribute to the form:checkbox tag won't work either.

My input is surrounded by a div so basically using the label attribute on the form:checkbox with the onmouseup call on the div would work but it feels kinda hacky.

So to sum it up I need either a different way to get my CSS to work or a way to achieve the above mentioned HTML structure using Spring.

The CSS (the rest is just styling which should not be important but I will post it if it'll help just let me know):

```
.switch input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after{
    left: 23px;
}

.switch input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label{
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: .switch input[type="checkbox"]:checked + input + label:after{
     left: 23px;
    }

    .switch input[type="checkbox"]:checked + input + label{
     background-color: #A539BD;
    }

Doesn't work either :S

Comment: Marco, i'm a little bit confused.. you want to keep this HTML structure and use an CSS wich add some style just in the label after the checkbox is checked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I correctly understood your question, here is your solution: https://jsfiddle.net/DiogoBernardelli/rLutkcx0/

I added the `input[type="hidden"]` between checkbox and label.

The code will look like:

```
.switch input[type="checkbox"]:checked + input[type="hidden"] + label:after{
    left: 23px;
}

.switch input[type="checkbox"]:checked + input[type="hidden"] + label{
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #f00; //just to emphasize the label
}
```

Comment: If it doesn't helped you, add a comment and I will try to help you out.

Comment: No this did it for me thanks a lot  *-* but why does it only work with the [type="hidden"] and not without it (see my first comment on the question) :S

Comment: If you want to do it without the hidden field or move it to after the label tag, just remove the "+ input[type="hidden"]" in our solution. You can learn about this "+" selector here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139763/what-does-the-plus-sign-css-selector-mean

Comment: the hidden input field is generated by the spring tag so it kinda has to be there :S ;D

Comment: Gotcha. So, u will have to use the "+" selector do make it work. U can also try the ">" selector and remove the "input[type="hidden"]" from the code, maybe it will work either. Btw, don`t forget the vote up on my main answer haha.

Comment: I'm ratrher new here it tells me that i can't upvote yet but i will do it as soon as I can :D