# HTML order of Input and Label elements affecting Style

Tags: html, css, input, label

I have a list of checkboxes and labels. I'm using this CSS to apply a style to the label when the checbox is checked:

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked + .CheckLabels {background-color: green;}
```

When I order my HTML like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="C" id="checkC" value="C" checked>
<label class="CheckLabels" for="checkC">C</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="D" id="checkD" value="D" checked>
<label class="CheckLabels" for="checkD">D</label>
```

It works as intended: clicking the C label adds or removes a green style. However, when I put label *before* the input, clicking the label causes the *following* label to have the style applied/removed. Ie: Clicking the C label adds or removes the green from the *D* label (though the proper checkbox is still checked.)

```
<label class="CheckLabels" for="checkC">C</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="C" id="checkC" value="C" checked>
<label class="CheckLabels" for="checkD">D</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="D" id="checkD" value="D" checked>
```

Why is this happening? I'm not particularly attached to the order of the labels and checkboxes, since I'll be using `display:none`. But it would be nice to know what is going on.

Comment: If you're just trying to understand the `+` selector, this question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139763/what-does-the-plus-sign-css-selector-mean

Answer (score 0):

That is related to the fact that the `a+b` selector selects the `b` placed directly after the `a`.

Therefore (when labels are put before inputs) the `label` right after the C `input` is the D `label`.

Answer (score 0):

`+` is a sibling selector. It specifically selects for A + B, in that order, i.e., it selects element B when it follows element A.

In form, it's analogous to the descendant selector, e.g., `div p`, which selects any `p` inside a `div`, and the direct descendant selector, e.g., `div > p`, which selects a `p` only if it's the direct child (and not grandchild) of a `div`.

The + is a direct sibling, but there's also a useful general sibling selector, e.g., `p ~ p` would select any `p` preceded by a `p` under the same parent.

Check out the MDN article on this specifically, and then read around on related selectors: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors