# How to use <a> links to show DIV on hover CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to show div on hover using css but can't seem to work with the pseudo-class  elements.

I think that this would have to do with the hover rule to the anchor elements with class and descendant child but can't seem to find any reference for it.

```css
.page-link2 {
 display: none;
}

.row > .col-md-3 > a.menu-link2:hover + .page-link2 {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <ul>
        <li class="menu-link1" ><a href="#">Page1</a></li>
        <li class="menu-link2" ><a href="#">Page2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <div class="page-link2"><p>test text</p></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your problem is how you're trying to use the + selector. It selects the very next sibling element relative to the preceeding selector - see here for further info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139763/what-does-the-plus-sign-css-selector-mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your child combinators (`>`) don't reach the `a.menu-link2` as is. A correct way to target it using child combinators would be

```
.row > .col-md-3 > ul > a.menu-link2:hover
```

because you missed the `<ul>` child. (The `>`-selector targets children, not grandchildren)

Secondly, you're using an adjacent sibling selector (`+`) to try and target an element that is not an adjacent sibling, but an element somewhere else.

You either need to move the `<div class="page-link2">` *into* your `<li>`, so that you can select it on hover, or use javascript to react to the hover and display the element then.