# Show mat-icon on hover

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I have `mat-list` in my html template:

```
<mat-list *ngFor="let item of items">
  <mat-list-item><mat-icon>add</mat-icon> {{ item.title }}</mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

I want to display `mat-icon` only on `mat-list-item` hover. So I come up with this css:

```
mat-icon {
  display: none;
}

mat-list-item:hover + mat-icon {
  display: block;
}
```

But for some reason it is does not work

However if I do try to change the background color it is works:

```
mat-list-item:hover {
  background-color: #3f51b5;
}
```

It is probably something to do with `mat-icon` 
Thoughts?

Comment: did you try with display: block !important ?

Comment: @BiswajitNath just did, still does not work

Comment: @sreginogemoh why are you using the `+` sign. Use the child operator here `>` or just remove `+`.

Comment: :host::ng-deep mat-icon { display:block !important }.. try this

Comment: By default mat-icon has display property 'inline-block'. Probably you need to set it on hover instead of display 'block'.
Issue can be because of the container with overflow:hidden, so when you use 'block' mat-icon goes down under previous block and is not visible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this

```
mat-icon{
  display: none;
}

mat-list-item:hover mat-icon{
  display: block;
}
```

you do not need [`+ adjacent selectors`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139763/what-does-the-plus-sign-css-selector-mean)

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-list-aoel4k?file=app/app.component.css)

Comment: How would you make sure that the `+` does not move the text to the right when it is displayed?

Comment: @sreginogemoh use `visibility: hidden;` and `visibility: visible;` to preserve the space of plus icon

Answer (score 2):

**You can try this code here :**

```
mat-icon{
  display: none;
}

mat-list-item:hover mat-icon{ display: block; }
```

OR

```
mat-list-item:hover > mat-icon{ display: block; }
```

You tried the **item:hover `+` children** it's not currect, beacus the `+` selector is the imedite sibling selector, it's not select children.

I give the two code here

1. **`mat-list-item:hover mat-icon{ display: block; }`** that means any children inside the **mat-list-item** class select this.
2. and the other hand **`mat-list-item:hover > mat-icon{ display: block; }`** this means the children but it's select the direct children as like ul > li it's select directed children, not children children.

this is the concept of the CSS selector 
You can learn more about CSS selectors: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp
or https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/trysel.asp

**Thank you**

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  mat-icon {
      display: none;
    }

    mat-list-item:hover > mat-icon {
      display: block;
    }
```