# Jquery can't find class with '+'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have these class with `"+"` string for eg. `crg-th-post-gsm+bb-sub-sub-all-programs` but the problem is when I try to `$('.crg-th-post-gsm+bb-sub-sub-all-programs')` jquery can't seem to find it because of the '+' I tried testing it without the `"+"` it works fine. How can I make it work with `"+"`? is there a way?

another workaround I can also think is replace the string "+" using .replace but when I use the `string.replace(/+/g,'-')` it does not recognize.

Comment: Just a note. You can have multiple classes. like class='class1 class2'. So if the + is to represent that you have more than 1 classes it might not be necessary.

Comment: Have a look at this, it might help your understanding https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

Comment: The reason this is an issue is because `+` has a meaning for a selector, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139763/what-does-the-plus-sign-css-selector-mean

Comment: I would highly suggest changing your class name, otherwise you'll have to escape that class *everywhere*. Why put yourself through that?

Comment: @TylerRoper it comes from data retrieved from users so I can't remotely change that. I expect there will be instance like this so I don't want to handle this by changing the class. Another option may be replacing all the possible "+"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `escapeSelector` [doc](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.escapeSelector/):

```js
console.log($('.' + $.escapeSelector("crg-th-post-gsm+bb-sub-sub-all-programs" )).text());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="crg-th-post-gsm+bb-sub-sub-all-programs">TEXT</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `+` with `\\`

```js
$('.crg-th-post-gsm\\+bb-sub-sub-all-programs').text( 'Hello there' );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="crg-th-post-gsm+bb-sub-sub-all-programs"></div>
```