# Styling input placeholder when input is read-only

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to style my input placeholder property only when the input is read-only but I can't seem to get the two selectors to work together, is this possible? I've tried a few variations but thought the below should work;

```
input:read-only + ::placeholder { color: black !important; }
```

...and to ensure max browser comptibility

```
input:read-only + ::-webkit-input-placeholder, input:read-only + ::placeholder, input:-moz-read-only + ::placeholder, input:read-only + ::-ms-input-placeholder { color: black  !important; }
```

None of these work, is this possible? Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following solution:

```css
input[readonly]::placeholder {
  color: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Hey StackOverflow" readonly/>
<input type="text" placeholder="Hey StackOverflow"/>
```

---

**Browser Compatibility / Can I use?**

- https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-placeholder
- https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-read-only-write

---

**Why your CSS rules doesn't work?**

Your CSS rules to format the placeholder tries to access a following placeholder (placeholder after `<input>` element). The placeholder is on the `<input>` element itself, so your rules doesn't match.

```css
p + p {
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<p>Hello</p>
<p>StackOverflow</p>
```

**more:** [Explanation of the `+` sign in CSS rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139763/what-does-the-plus-sign-css-selector-mean)

Comment: That's got it, thanks! Do you know what the browser compatible versions are? I tried editing all versions of the selector but it breaks them all (eg input[-moz-readonly]::placeholder, input[readonly]::-ms-input-placeholder)

Answer (score 3):

The Placeholder is not a child of the `input` so no space is needed in the selector.

```css
input:read-only::placeholder {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="You can't type here!" readonly>
```