# how to get paragraph element displayed on hovered over input element

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

I have input element and paragraph element, I want the p element to be displayed only on hovering over the input element.

Here is what I tried

```
<html>
 <body>
 <div class="overlay">
   <input id="inputCustomer" value="sometext">
 </div>
 <div class="content">
  <p id="spandiv">This the p element</p>
 </div>
 </body>
 <style>
    #spandiv {
        background-color: #232F34;
        color:#FFFFFF;
        opacity:0;
    }

    #inputCustomer:hover + #spandiv {
    display: block;
    opacity:1;
    }

 </style>
</html>
```

Comment: you can use css to achieve the required effect `.div_class_name:hover { display: block; };`

Comment: I have changed question <div id="overlay"> is changed to <div class="overlay">

Comment: and you have to hide your p on default

Comment: yes thats why opacity:0 on hovering I make opacity :1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use [plus sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139763/what-does-the-plus-sign-css-selector-mean), you must put all of the selectors in the same level:

```css
#spandiv {
    background-color: #232F34;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    opacity:0;
}

#inputCustomer:hover + #spandiv {
    display: block;
    opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
   <input id="inputCustomer" value="sometext">
   <p id="spandiv">This the p element</p>
 </div>
```

---

JavaScript version (to use them in different levels):

```js
document.getElementById('inputCustomer').addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
  document.getElementById('spandiv').style.opacity = 1;
});

document.getElementById('inputCustomer').addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
  document.getElementById('spandiv').style.opacity = 0;
});
```

```css
#spandiv {
    background-color: #232F34;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
 <div class="overlay">
   <input id="inputCustomer" value="sometext">
 </div>
 <div class="content">
  <p id="spandiv">This the p element</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: Hi , Thanks for answer, I need selectors to be at different level on some purpose

Comment: @karansys In that case, you can use javascript or jquery instead. You can edit your question and I will update my answer with it.

Comment: thats perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

By using mouseenter (add class .show to the paragraph) and mouseleave (remove class .show from the paragraph). In the style you can define class .show

```
<style>
#spandiv {
  display: block;
  background-color: #232f34;
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 0;
}
#spandiv.show {
  opacity: 1;
}
</style>

<div class="overlay">
  <input id="inputCustomer" value="sometext">
</div>
<div class="content">
  <p id="spandiv">This the p element</p>
</div>

<script>
var input = document.getElementById("inputCustomer");
var paragraph = document.getElementById("spandiv");
input.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(e) {
  paragraph.classList.add('show');
});
input.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(e) {
  paragraph.classList.remove('show');
});
</script>
```