# CSS - psuedo-class for first <p> after another tag

Tags: css

Is there an equivalent for the psuedo-class, *first-of-type*, but applies to, e.g., a <p> preceded by a <hr>, rather than just applying to the first child-tag?

As an example, I'd like first-of-type to apply to both paragraphs preceded by <h1>, rather than just the first:

```
<head>
  <style>
    p{text-indent:1%;}
    p:first-of-type{text-indent:0%;}
  </style>
  <title>Mara's Tale</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Chapter 1</h1>
  <p>This is a first-of-type.</p>
  <p>But this isn't (good!).</p>

  <h1>Chapter 2</h1>
  <p>This is not first-of-type, but I'd like it to be.</p>
  <p>This is not first-of-type (good!).</p>
</body>
</html>
```

At the moment, I'm running a regex to add a class to any <p> not preceded by </p>, but, as a solution, it irks me.

**Update to add:**

Heh - for some reason, this confused the hell out of my Sony e-reader*, which then started ignoring a valid first-of-type.

I had to change this CSS:

```
p:first-of-type{
  text-indent: 0%;
}

p.dinkus {
  text-align: center;
  text-indent: 0%;
  font-size: 125%;
  margin-top: 6%;
  margin-bottom: 4%;
  white-space: pre;
}

p.dinkus + p{
  text-indent: 0%;
}
```

To this:

```
h1 + p{
  text-indent: 0%;
}

p.dinkus {
  text-align: center;
  text-indent: 0%;
  font-size: 125%;
  margin-top: 6%;
  margin-bottom: 4%;
  white-space: pre;
}

p.dinkus + p{
  text-indent: 0%;
}
```

Just to clarify, my general structure is:

```
<h1>Chapter 3</h1>
<p>Opening para - don't indent.</p>
<p>Non-opening para - do indent.</p>
<p class="dinkus">*                *                *</p>
<p>Para following a dinkus - don't indent.</p>
<p>Non-opening para, not following a dinkus - do indent.</p>
```

* seems to be a Sony bug - Sigle and Calibre had no issues

Comment: You cannot traverse up the DOM tree with CSS . Only down. From parent to child.

Comment: If the paragraph is ALWAYS preceded by the heading then yes. H1+p

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the "+" (plus sign) CSS selector mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139763/what-does-the-plus-sign-css-selector-mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use the `CSS element+element Selector` in this case h1 + p should target all `<p>` tag that is preceded by `h1` tag.

```css
 h1 + p{
  text-indent:1%;
  color: red
 }
```

```html
  <title>Mara's Tale</title>


  <h1>Chapter 1</h1>
  <p>This is a first-of-type.</p>
  <p>But this isn't (good!).</p>

  <h1>Chapter 2</h1>
  <p>This is not first-of-type, but I'd like it to be.</p>
  <p>This is not first-of-type (good!).</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `x + y` selector. It selects all y elements that are placed immediately after x elements

```css
p {text-indent:1%; color: red; }
h1 + p {text-indent:0%; color: blue; }
```

```html
<h1>Chapter 1</h1>
  <p>This is a first-of-type.</p>
  <p>But this isn't (good!).</p>

  <h1>Chapter 2</h1>
  <p>This is not first-of-type, but I'd like it to be.</p>
  <p>This is not first-of-type (good!).</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `+` selector, which basically means the one after.

So, in your case, that means you can simply use:

```
h1 + p
```

which will let you target the p after the h1.

If you ever want to target *all* the p elements after a h1, you just change the `+` to a `~`

You can then apply CSS rules as normal for this :)

---

By the way, here is a diagram [I made earlier for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139763/what-does-the-plus-sign-css-selector-mean/64505377#64505377), which should help explain this:

[image: the + selector targets the one after, and the ~ selector targets all the ones after]