# CSS Hover Will Not Work When Selecting Another Element

Tags: html, css

When hovering over the span I would like the H1 element to turn blue. However, it does not. What am I doing wrong?

```css
span:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
span:hover h1 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<span>HOVER</span>
<h1>test</h1>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The H1 is not a child of the span it's a sibling so you need the sibling combinator `+` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator

```css
span:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
span:hover + h1 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<span>HOVER</span>
<h1>test</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139763/what-does-the-plus-sign-css-selector-mean) for what does the “+” (plus sign) CSS selector mean?

```css
span:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
span:hover + h1 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<span>HOVER</span>
<h1>test</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Inorder to style the adjecent sibling you have to use `+` like `span:hover + h1`

```css
span:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

span:hover + h1 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<span>HOVER</span>
<h1>test</h1>
```

`span:hover h1` tries to find `h1` node inside the `span` while its in hover state. This will be working when your layout is in below format only.

```css
span:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

span:hover h1 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<span>
  HOVER
  <h1>test</h1>
</span>
```

Refer [this](https://techbrij.com/css-selector-adjacent-child-sibling) document for much more understanding regarding css selectors.