# How do I make the CSS hover effect to work?

Tags: html, css

The simple test I did unde the main divs works as intended, but the main one does not.
I've tried putting the class "services-icon" on the div that holds the image, still not working.

I notices in the test one that if I put another div or p between the img and existing p, it does not work anymore. So I've tried removing the chip-title div from the main code between my targets, and it's still not working.

```css
.services-hide {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.services-icon:hover+.services-hide {
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="chip-card">
  <div class="chip-img">
    <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/6176/6176756.png" class="services-icon" width="100">
  </div>
  <div class="chip-title">
    <h4>Title</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="chip-description">
    <p class="services-hide">Part that needs to be hidden</p>
  </div>
</div>
<!--test-->
<img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/6176/6176756.png" class="services-icon" width="100">
<p class="services-hide chip-description">test hidden part</p>
```

Comment: `.services-icon:hover + .services-hide` styles the next sibling being `.services-hide` after the hovered `.services-icon` .. it's not clear how did you expect to style an element being in a different scope related to the hovered element otherwise

Comment: [What does the "+" (plus sign) CSS selector mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139763/what-does-the-plus-sign-css-selector-mean)

Comment: maybe what you are looking for is changing the html structure so that the `.services-icon` direct parent contains also the `.services-hide`. That's because a css selector cannot travel upwards (unless using `:has` but it's not yet fully adopted). The key is putting in relation those two elements because the first one is the trigger to style the second.

Comment: `.chip-card:has(.services-icon:hover) .services-hide` but you will be blasted for using such an early feature [https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Ahas](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Ahas)

Comment: Thank you both! I understood now how the "+" works and made some modifications so that it fits my code too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+` in `.services-icon:hover+.services-hide` means you're trying to apply styles on the next element of `service-icon` with the class name `services-hide` (`:hover` is the state). Your problem here is that `services-hide` is the child element of `chip-description`, so you can not get the sibling element `services-hide` directly from `chip-img` or `chip-title`.

Let's assume that you don't want to have the title element. You can try the below approach. Don't forget the space between `.chip-description` and `.services-hide`.

```css
.services-hide {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.chip-img:hover + .chip-description .services-hide {
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-color: pink;
}

.services-icon:hover+.services-hide {
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="chip-card">
  <div class="chip-img">
    <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/6176/6176756.png" class="services-icon" width="100">
  </div>
  <div class="chip-description">
    <p class="services-hide">Part that needs to be hidden</p>
  </div>
</div>
<!--test-->
<img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/6176/6176756.png" class="services-icon" width="100">
<p class="services-hide chip-description">test hidden part</p>
```

If you don't want to remove the title element, you can group them with another element with the class name `chip-main`. In this case, the sibling of `chip-main` will be `chip-description`. We can use the selector `.chip-main + .chip-description .services-hide` (Don't forget the space between `.chip-description` and `.services-hide`).

```css
.services-hide {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.chip-main:hover + .chip-description .services-hide {
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-color: pink;
}

.services-icon:hover + .services-hide {
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="chip-card">
  <div class="chip-main">
    <div class="chip-img">
      <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/6176/6176756.png" class="services-icon" width="100">
    </div>
    <div class="chip-title">
      <h4>Title</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="chip-description">
    <p class="services-hide">Part that needs to be hidden</p>
  </div>
</div>
<!--test-->
<img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/6176/6176756.png" class="services-icon" width="100">
<p class="services-hide chip-description">test hidden part</p>
```

If you don't want to get trouble with the child element selector, you can move the class `services-hide` to the element `chip-description`.

```css
.services-hide {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.chip-main:hover + .services-hide {
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-color: pink;
}

.services-icon:hover + .services-hide {
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="chip-card">
  <div class="chip-main">
    <div class="chip-img">
      <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/6176/6176756.png" class="services-icon" width="100">
    </div>
    <div class="chip-title">
      <h4>Title</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="chip-description services-hide">
    <p>Part that needs to be hidden</p>
  </div>
</div>
<!--test-->
<img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/6176/6176756.png" class="services-icon" width="100">
<p class="services-hide chip-description">test hidden part</p>
```